# Embedding Video Into A Java Application?

Tags: java, swing, video

I want to put a video on my Java Swing application.

For example, I can use...

```
g.drawString("Hello!",100,100);
```

To draw a string. But how do I put a video there?

Answer (score 2):

Here do try these links

- [DEITEL](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060422/PlayingVideowithJMF/)
- [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/)

And do try to run these files, hope these can help

[MEDIA](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/media/media.zip)

For this project to work, you have to download first Java Media Framework from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)

Comment: Are there options for something that reads from a file rather than the internet?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "easy way" for doing this if you want your player to be able to playback all sorts of videos. Try using [GStreamer for Java](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/) from Google-Code...

Comment: Ahha, I didn't knew about this being on Google Apps too :-)